# jquery remove duplicate from multidimensionalarray

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

```
[{
    "basicinfo": [{
        "ID": "015-08-0011-000-01",
    }],
    "owner": [{
        "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
        "lastname": "James",
        "firstname": "Leborn",
        "type": "Basketball",
        "suffix": "",
        "Address": [{
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "23",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "23",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "1",
            "city": "city2",
            "town": "town2",
            "district": "district2",
            "street": "34",
            "zipcode": "1218"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "1",
            "city": "city2",
            "town": "town2",
            "district": "district2",
            "street": "34",
            "zipcode": "1218"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "23",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "23",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "1",
            "city": "city2",
            "town": "town2",
            "district": "district2",
            "street": "34",
            "zipcode": "1218"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "342-432-423-000",
            "contactflag": "1",
            "city": "city2",
            "town": "town2",
            "district": "district2",
            "street": "34",
            "zipcode": "1218"
        }],
        "mobile": "23432432",
        "landline": "123123",
        "email": "asdad@adad.com"
    }, {
        "ownerid": "897-862-314-000",
        "lastname": "De La Hoya",
        "firstname": "Oscar",
        "ownershipfrom": "09\/01\/2015",
        "type": "Boxing",
        "suffix": "jr",
        "Address": [{
            "ownerid": "897-862-314-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "897-862-314-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "897-862-314-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }, {
            "ownerid": "897-862-314-000",
            "contactflag": "0",
            "city": "city1",
            "town": "town1",
            "district": "district1",
            "street": "",
            "zipcode": "4311"
        }],
        "mobile": "23432432",
        "landline": "123123",
        "email": "asdad@adad.com"
    }]
}];
```

In the above object how can I remove the duplicate record in address. I only want one record per contact flag. This contact really represent temporary and permanent address. I get this from php select record. I have tried getting the duplicated in php side but i didnt succeed so i might as well try in js side.

`FYI`

Data in database is not duplicate

Comment: Don't. Fix your broken PHP. It's *not wise* (to be polite) to send data from server to client and have the client sift the mess the server created.

Comment: If in the database there is no duplicate records maybe you have some error in your query?

Comment: @CliffBurton i fix every thing the other records are not duplicate the address is the only duplicate and i dont know how to remove it i will post the way how i created the multidimensional from query so you can give suggestion